# intelliJ IDEA: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, sql, intellij-idea

I have downloaded the java connector and added it to my external library, however I am still unable to connect to my database. The error occurs at

Class.forName(driver);

Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I've attached a screenshot which should show everything that you need to know.

[image: Picture]

SOLUTION: Turns out, you have to put the entire downloaded file in the External Library, not just the folder that its located in

Comment: I believe this is not a maven project. so check project libs on project structure

Comment: The driver is not on the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

you can add mysql connector via maven dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

or you can download jar file manually at [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) or search on internet

then add downloaded jar file to your lib directory in project

right click on file at intellij and select 'Add as library'

Comment: I have added it as a library though. It still doesn't work

Comment: @Workkkkk please try some tutorial step by step some like this one: https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database
please doanload jar file and at it again from this tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue and this is what worked for me .
**Right- Click on your Project --> Maven --> Reload Project .**
Now the mysql-connector dependency was added under the External Libraries.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOqU2.png)
I am now able to establish connection to my MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just leaving this here in case it helps someone.

In my case, I cloned the repo that had the pom.xml file with an old driver that is not compatible with my local database. After cloning, I opened IntelliJ, ran the project and got the same error. Then I changed the pom.xml file with a newer driver and got into this rabbit hole.

The simple fix:

1. Clone again the repo
2. Open the pom.xml file with notepad or something else **before** opening IntelliJ.
3. Update the pom.xml with the latest connector.
4. Open IntelliJ
5. Run project
   Worked at the first try.

I don't know what IntelliJ does when opening a project for the first time that I cannot change afterwards. I'm sure there must be a settings somewhere that fixes since I can't find it this but this tricked helped me .

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5Hey0e2Y_g

This will definitely work. But if you get an error saying,'Exporting a package from system module is not allowed with --release', then you should do the following.

Go to File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Java Compiler:
Under 'Project bytecode version' write the version of java you are using. But keep in mind that you should be using java version 11+. I've tried it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, in your "External Libraries Folder", there is a folder that contains various Jars provided by java. Right click on that folder (highlighted in picture attached) and click on "Open Library Settings".

[image: Just a picture of where you have to right click on]

It will open up a new window that will have all the jars listed up. Just below the list of all the jars you will find "+" and "-" symbols, click on the "+" symbol and add the mysql-connector jar by selecting it from the File Explorer.

Your application should work now, I am not really sure if it's the correct way to do it, but it works.

Comment: They already have that jar inside the project. See screenshot.

Comment: In the question's screenshot the jar is not inside the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk, in my answer I meant to include the jar inside this folder, not outside it. 

Questions Screenshot:
External Libraries => (This is where they placed the jar)

My Answer:
External Libraries => <1.8> => (This is where I am asking them to place the jar)

Comment: When you add any jar besides jre, it'll go in External Libraries folder only, no matter the location of that jar in your computer. How do you create a folder inside that?

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt Here's how my folder structure looks like. https://ibb.co/gjg87B1