# Can't set up connector for MySQL (MariaDB) in Java using IntelliJ on Linux (Manjaro)

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, mariadb, mysql-connector

I am doing some minor project for my work using Java with IntelliJ IDEA as IDE and Gradle.
I decided to use MySQL database inside of my project.
I installed MySQL from Manjaro repository and choose default MariaDB

Installation and setup was successful - server working fine on my local machine and I can manipulate databases and tables from command line

Next step for me was to add database to java.
To do so I used
`DriverManager class` from `java.sql.*`

BTW this database will be used on my local machine only

Next step was to upload driver.

It was a bit struggle for me because I was unsure which one to pick - `mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar` or `mariadb-java-client-3.2.0-sources.jar`

I found an info that DriverManager will choose appropriate for me so it is not a big deal - so I downloaded both.

Then I first met my problem - an error telling me that

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
    at DatabaseHandler.main(DatabaseHandler.java:11)
```

I checked breakpoints and find out that collection size where `DriverManager` stores all found drivers was equal to 0 so I thought that my problem is in `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Here is my code where I try to create simple interaction with DB:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseHandler {
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";
    static final String USER = "max";
    static final String PASS = "12345";
    static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Users";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open a connection
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
            // Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getInt("id"));
                System.out.print(", Age: " + rs.getInt("age"));
                System.out.print(", First: " + rs.getString("first"));
                System.out.println(", Last: " + rs.getString("last"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So far I tried to set up `CLASSPATH` with
`export CLASSPATH=/home/max/code/libs`.

So this path is where my jars are.
Also I tried to add names of those jars after libs... Still same error

I tried to copy those jars into java-related folder but still miss...

I found out that IntelliJ itself has some kind of it's own IDEA_CLASSPATH or something but adding to this value also did nothing

Could you please tell me in which direction should I think or where did I get things wrong?

Currently using Linux Manjaro / IntelliJ Idea / Gradle

Comment: Try following - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72752009/584420 if you have the mysql driver jar downloaded. Then register the driver and the rest of the steps. If you want to do maven way, follow the other answers of the same post.

Comment: If you use Gradle, then you shoudn't download and install and manipulate the classpath manually. The only thing you should do is to add the dependency to the gradle file (and reimport in IntelliJ).

Comment: You can search for the package like here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/3.2.0. The tabs below contain the exact code to add to your build file.

Comment: @vanje - I feel myself really silly right now

I could't find exact place where I could find gradle dependencies so I always skipped a mvnrepository.com thinking it's only about Maven

Thank you so much - adding just a one line solved my 8-hour problem

Comment: `static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/testdb";` actually, if you're using mariadb-server